# XAML Почему Grid не выравнивается по ширине (HorizontalAligment=Stretch)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть следующая разметка:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="system:String" x:Key="Array">
            <system:String>String1</system:String>
            <system:String>String2String2</system:String>
            <system:String>String3String3String3</system:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource Array}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Второй объект"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Я хочу, чтобы в ListBox отображалось содержимое строки и какая-нибудь еще информация следом. Для этого я использую свойство ItemTemplate, куда кладу Grid, делю его на две ColumnDefinition и хочу, чтобы в первой колонке содержалась одна информация, во второй другая. Мне ПРИНЦИПИАЛЬНО чтобы внутренний grid делил контейнер, в котором находится ListBox на две равные части **относительно внешнего контейнера**, и уже в каждой из них отображал соответствующую информацию. Но я как понимаю, он для каждого объекта создает отдельный Grid, и имеет ширину относительно длины содержимого ListBox.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать так, чтобы внутренний Grid делил Item в ListBox пополам относительно внешнего контейнера?

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос. У `ListBox` надо установить свойство:

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
```

Но все равно для каждого `ListBoxItem`, как я понял, будут создаваться новый объект `Grid`, что, скорее всего, не есть хорошо.

---

PS Если знаете, как оптимизировать, буду рад ответу

Comment: *для каждого ListBoxItem будут создаваться новый объект Grid* — да, но это нормально

Comment: Есть ещё ItemContainerStyle, иногда может пригодиться